# Display table with 'display: block;' at the center of a page

Tags: html, css

I have a very large table that doesn't fit a page and I added horizontal scrollbar like this:

```
  .table-x-scroll {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And `<table class="table-x-scroll">...</table>`
But I also want my table to be in the center of a page. I used to use `align="center"` but now, when I added `display: block` it doesn't work. Table is always at the left. How can I do these two things at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be better to use a wrapper for the table and add overflow to that wrapper not the table it self. This way you can control the behavior better.

And also use `margin:0 auto` on table to center it horizontally. No need for `display:block`

See below or better in [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zu6jdw3e/10/)

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Fairy glad i could help. Cheers :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` in your style and specify the `width`

```css
.table-x-scroll {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-x-scroll" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <row>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>BB</td>
    </row>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not change anything. Table is still left justified

Comment: @Fairy you need to specify the `width`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Margin : 0 auto

```
.table-x-scroll {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin : 0 auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that others have answered the aligning problem. But i couldn't see the "Doesn't fit to page" error so here is a solution for that:

In the css you specified `overflow-x: auto;`
If you change that to `overflow-x scroll;` it will make it scale to whatever size you choose to specify. and make it scrollable. The scrollbar within is possible to edit/remove, but it will still scroll ^^

I personally recommend the `vw,vh` values
example:

`.bunnydiv {font-size: 1vw, 1vh;}` This will make it scale to 1% of the width and of the height of the monitor. This can be specified with either `vh, vw`, `vh` and `vw`. Not both paramaters are needed, and it will scale accordingly :-)

I found some code I made myself some time ago, use this as a reference :-)

```
.div_scroll
    {overflow-y: scroll;
        display: block;
            top:0px;
                right: 0px;
                    position: absolute;
                       transform: translate(-23.6vw, 15vh);
                          border: 3px solid #dddddd; 
                             max-height: 75vh;
                                width: 76vw;
                                    margin: 0px;
                                      background-color: white;}
```

It's copy-pasted, and setup this way for readability. Don't format you code like this unless it works better for you :-)